# How to annualize sharpe ratio using quarterly data?

Tags: risk, sharpe-ratio

Say I have quarterly returns data for a stock. I am currently calculating rolling Sharpe ratios using an eight-quarter forward window. So for example, say I have quarterly returns data starting in 2000Q1, then 2000Q2, 2000Q3, 2000Q4, etc.

What I do is take the arithmetic average of the quarterly returns from 2000Q1 all the way until 2001Q4 (so basically just the average of 8 returns). Then I calculate the standard deviation of these quarterly returns (so again, just the standard deviation of 8 returns). Then I subtract the risk-free rate from the average returns and divide the whole thing by the standard deviation to get the Sharpe ratio for this window.

I then repeat the same process but using the quarterly returns from 2000Q2 to 2002Q1 to calculate the Sharpe ratio for the next window.

Now say I get a Sharpe ratio of 0.51 for the first window. How do I interpret this number? Do I say this is the quarterly Sharpe ratio? (Because it is estimated using quarterly returns?) But then, say I use a different window of 12 quarters (instead of 8), I do the exact same calculation, now the first window Sharpe ratio becomes 0.66. Is this also a "quarterly" Sharpe ratio? How would I compare between 0.51 and 0.66? Surely they can't be directly comparable because one is estimated using 8 quarters of data while another is estimated using 12 quarters of data. How can I "annualize" both so that they are comparable?

Comment: Instead of taking arithmetic averages, I'd just compute the total return on the period you're interested in, annualize it, subtract from it the risk-free rate and divide it by the annualized volatility.

Comment: I am following the formula given in Eqn (4) here http://web.stanford.edu/~wfsharpe/art/sr/sr.htm, which is used to calculate ex-post Sharpe ratio. Doesn't the formula show that we should use the average returns?

Comment: Because the returns periods are both quarterly, these are both quarterly numbers.
(More precisely the _units_ of the SR of each of these is $qtr^{-1/2}$.) You expect to get different results for different periods of time because the data are not the same.